# "Être doué de/en/pour"

Tags: grammaire, expressions

What is the correct way to say "to be gifted with"? I have seen "*être doué* ***de***" but also "*être doué* ***pour***" and "*être doué* ***en***"

- Is it all correct?
- What is the difference between them?

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are 3 different cases.

The translation you are looking for seems to be *Être doué de*, even though it is not very frequently used. *Être doué de* is usually followed by some ability that one naturally has. A common instance may be *L'être humain est un être doué de conscience*, which one can translate to "Human beings are beings provided with consciousness".

*Être doué pour* is followed by some action that one has some skills in. For instance *Être doué pour jouer de la musique* refers to someone who is good at playing music.

Finally, *Être bon en* is very similar to *Être doué pour*, except that it is followed by a domain one is skilled in, rather than an action. For instance *Être bon en mathématiques* refers to someone who is skilled in maths.